# Generate seperate XML file for each mysql table row using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have this function in php script to generate xml file from mysql table.

```
    function createXMLfile($stackarray){

    $filePath = '/root/stack.xml';

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

    $root = $dom->createElement('REQUEST');

    for($i=0; $i<count($stackarray); $i++){

        $stackName    =  $stackarray[$i]['stack_name']; 

        $stackSERIAL      =  $stackarray[$i]['stack_serialnumber']; 

        $content = $dom->createElement('CONTENT');

        $device = $dom->createElement('DEVICE');

        $info = $dom->createElement('INFO');

        $name   = $dom->createElement('NAME', $stackName); 

        $info->appendChild($name);  

        $serial     = $dom->createElement('SERIAL', $stackSERIAL); 

        $info->appendChild($serial);

        $type     = $dom->createElement('TYPE', "NETWORKING"); 

        $info->appendChild($type);

        $device->appendChild($info);

        $root->appendChild($content);

        $module     = $dom->createElement('MODULEVERSION', "3.1");

        $content->appendChild($module);

        $process     = $dom->createElement('PROCESSNUMBER', "1");

        $content->appendChild($process);

        $content->appendChild($device);        

        $deviceid = $dom->createElement('DEVICEID', "foo");

        $root->appendChild($deviceid);

        $query     = $dom->createElement('QUERY', "SNMPQUERY");

        $root->appendChild($query);

    }

    $dom->appendChild($root); 

    $dom->save($filePath);
}
```

What it does currently is generating xml file for whole data in mysql table based on field mapping above. Eg;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<REQUEST>
  <CONTENT>
    <MODULEVERSION>3.1</MODULEVERSION>
    <PROCESSNUMBER>1</PROCESSNUMBER>
    <DEVICE>
      <INFO>
        <NAME>Nexus5020 Chassis</NAME>
        <SERIAL>SS613390FZT</SERIAL>
        <TYPE>NETWORKING</TYPE>
      </INFO>
    </DEVICE>
  </CONTENT>
  <DEVICEID>foo</DEVICEID>
  <QUERY>SNMPQUERY</QUERY>
  </REQUEST>
```

Mysql table structure looks like this

```
+----+------------------------+--------------------+
| id | stack_name             | stack_serialnumber |
+----+------------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | Nexus5020 Chassis      | SS613390FZT        |
|  2 | 40x10GE/Supervisor     | JA91344BHNK        |
|  3 | 6x10GE Ethernet Module | JA71228018M        |
|  4 | 8x1/2/4G FC Module     | JAB1531020C        |
|  5 | Nexus5020 Chassis      | SSI13390FZT        |
```

I want to generate **specific** XML file for each row based on the mysql data above using existing element mapping in the php code. Eg above table contains 5 rows so it should have **5** XML files generated.

How do I accomplish this? Someone pointed out to use array column feature `[array_column ( array $array , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )]` in the script. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think part of your problem is a confusion between what is a column and what is a row. Your example table has 3 columns (id, stack_name, stack_serialnumber) and 5 rows.

Comment: Another thing is, your function specifies a single file, and then makes a loop to iterate through each row, and then creates the single xml file. If you want a separate file for each row then you'll need to specify the filepath, and create the file both within the loop.

Comment: Thanks, @JaredC First result from google search failed me https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-rows-and-columns.html :(

Comment: The very first thing you see when opening that link is an image that shows columns going vertical, and rows going horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work to just put the creation of the document inside the loop. By adding the loops number `$i` to the filepath, you prevent overwriting the file on each iteration.

```
function createXMLfile($stackarray){
    for($i=0; $i<count($stackarray); $i++){
        $filePath = "/root/stack" . $i . ".xml";
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $root = $dom->createElement('REQUEST');
        $stackName    =  $stackarray[$i]['stack_name']; 
        $stackSERIAL      =  $stackarray[$i]['stack_serialnumber']; 
        $content = $dom->createElement('CONTENT');
        $device = $dom->createElement('DEVICE');
        $info = $dom->createElement('INFO');
        $name   = $dom->createElement('NAME', $stackName); 
        $info->appendChild($name);  
        $serial     = $dom->createElement('SERIAL', $stackSERIAL); 
        $info->appendChild($serial);
        $type     = $dom->createElement('TYPE', "NETWORKING"); 
        $info->appendChild($type);
        $device->appendChild($info);
        $root->appendChild($content);
        $module     = $dom->createElement('MODULEVERSION', "3.1");
        $content->appendChild($module);
        $process     = $dom->createElement('PROCESSNUMBER', "1");
        $content->appendChild($process);
        $content->appendChild($device);        
        $deviceid = $dom->createElement('DEVICEID', "foo");
        $root->appendChild($deviceid);
        $query     = $dom->createElement('QUERY', "SNMPQUERY");
        $root->appendChild($query);
        $dom->appendChild($root); 
        $dom->save($filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Done. Thanks again buddy.